# The import com.ecyrd,jspwiki cannot be resolved in jsp page in jforum project

Tags: java, servlets

I downloaded jforum 2.1.9 project. And imported it into ecipse ee.

I moved all jsp pages into WebContent folder so that eclipse could deploy them correctly in tomcat 7.

But after move, jsp pages cannot resolve this import:

```
<%@ page import="com.ecyrd.jspwiki.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.ecyrd.jspwiki.filters.*" %>
```

How to fix this in jforum 2.1.9 project?

Can you tell me what jar should be added to classpath to solve this?

JSPWiki project can be found here https://www.ecyrd.com/JSPWiki/wiki/JSPWikiDownload. But I really understand nothing there.

Comment: which error you get ?

Comment: The import com.ecyrd.jspwiki cannot be resolved